# How to make an excel cell as a source file for a parameter for a query?

Tags: powerquery, excel-2016

I have a query on Excel query editor from multiple excel files, I changed the source to be a parameter, and the parameter type is a text. it worked. then I checked if I can make the parameter source is a query from excel cell ([Power Query Parameters – How to use Named Cells as Flexible Inputs](https://accessanalytic.com.au/powerquery_namedcells_parameters/). but I faced a problem that there is an error as below :
Formula.Firewall: Query 'XXXX' (step 'Source') references other queries or steps, so it may not directly access a data source. Please rebuild this data combination.

I checked Excelguru solution ( [Power Query Errors: Please Rebuild This Data Combination](https://www.excelguru.ca/blog/2015/03/11/power-query-errors-please-rebuild-this-data-combination/))

the point that the query I creates is a product from merged tables, Do I need to make a staging quires first before the merge, or any better idea?